Connecting Github Repo via Visual studio IDE
We have recently moved our github on-prem(enterprise) repositories to our enterprise cloud(EMU). While we connect the repository via Visual studio IDE 2019, we are able to clone the repository via https URL where our repository is authorized via fine-grained token.
Problem is that everytime we try to push the new changes to github server it keeps on asking for authorization Even-though the credential manager has the credentials stored. It is very frustrating to authorize every-time when a change is needed to be push to the github server.
Could any-one suggest a solution ?
Thanks
Diwakar
i tried to clean the credentials manager and set the git settings on the visual studio for GCM and tried the clone and pushed new changes..
I still see the authorization window everytime i push.
